# have error on Processmaker composer install

Tags: processmaker

I downloaded processmaker4 and have error on composer install:
Source path "/Users/nolan/src/laradock-packages/ProcessMaker/docker-executor-node" is not found for package processmaker/docker-executor-node

I installed php nodejs docker and...

Answer (score 0):

Someone has use a local library and push the changes to the repo. This route is in composer.lock (this file stores the library location after composer install).

You can delete the file a run composer install again.

In my case i have set memory_limit = -1 in php.ini to avoid memory limit errors during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Release ZIP posted in the release area of the github. It doesn't have any local dependencies. As for Composer, I recommend you use Composer v2. It's much faster and it doesn't require this memory_limit flag.

Releases: https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker/releases

Answer (score 0):

on OpenSuse 15.2 i need to do

```
$ sudo php artisan processmaker:install
```

or always get errors on docker install

if you are configure install first, then install composer in local path

```
$ cd vagrant/processmaker
```

then composer 2 install

```
$: php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"

$: php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '756890a4488ce9024fc62c56153228907f1545c228516cbf63f885e036d37e9a59d27d63f46af1d4d07ee0f76181c7d3') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"

$: php composer-setup.php

$: php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

then

```
$: php composer.phar install
```

and dispatch php artisan processmaker:install with sudo (i dont know why i need sudo but setup fail if not after migrations)

if you get source from @Alan Bollinger you dont neet compile assets for nodejs but you will need get always packages from composer